# Python sprintf and memset operations

Tags: c++, python, network-programming

I want to convert this particular portion of code in C++ to python
But i got stuck while doing the operations like memset and sprintf in python.
Can anyone help me to do the same in python.My code is as follows.

```
send(char* data)
{
/** COnvert From here **/
packetLength=strlen(data);
dataBuffer = new char[packetLength];
memset(dataBuffer, 0x00, packetLength);

char headerInfo[32];
memset(headerInfo, 0x00, sizeof (headerInfo));
sprintf(headerInfo, "%d", packetLength);

memcpy(dataBuffer, headerInfo, 32);
memcpy(dataBuffer + 32, data, packetLength);
/** Upto Here **/
//TODO send data via socket
}
```

These things i have tried

```
#headerInfo=bytearray()
                #headerInfo.insert(0,transactionId)
                #headerInfo.insert(self.headerParameterLength,(self.headerLength+len(xmlPacket)))
                #headerInfo=(('%16d'%transactionId).zfill(16))+(('%d'%(self.headerLength+len(xmlPacket))).zfill(16))
                #print("Sending packet for transaction "+(('%d'%transactionId).zfill(16))+" packetLength "+(('%d'%(self.headerLength+len(xmlPacket))).zfill(16)))
                #dataPacket=headerInfo+xmlPacket
                headerInfo=('%0x0016d'%transactionId)+('%0x00d'%(self.headerLength+len(xmlPacket)))
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to do the above c code in python

Comment: The answer is probably yes. There are always people who love to do someone else's work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf` in Python is achieved by using `%` or `.format`, e.g.:

```
headerInfo = '%d' % packetLength
# or,
headerInfo = '{0:d}'.format(packetLength)
# or even
headerInfo = str(packetLength)
```

A `memset`-like operation can be done via multiplication, e.g.:

```
headerInfo = '\0' * 32
```

However, these won't act like you expect, since strings are immutable. You need to do something like:

```
headerInfo = str(packetLength)
headerInfo += '\0' * (32 - len(headerInfo)) # pad the string
dataBuffer = headerInfo + data
```

Or use the `struct` module:

```
import struct
dataBuffer = struct.pack('32ss', str(packetLength), data)
```

(The `32s` format string will left-align the string and pad with NUL characters.)

---

If you are using Python 3, then you have to be careful about bytes vs strings. If you are dealing with network sockets etc. you want to make sure that everything is bytes, not unicode strings.

Comment: @AkhilThayyil, no problem, but on future questions, please indicate that you've made an effort (as in, post any Python code you've written), instead of just asking "write my code for me".

Comment: actualy requirement is little different and i tried so many things , pls find that in my edit , after that only i posted the question ...

Comment: @AkhilThayyil, use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct), my example should get you started.

Comment: the  "pad the string" method worked for me , rite now am using that , thank you again ...